# How can I write Persian in iTextPdf?

Tags: android, pdf, itext

- I use the iTextPdf library to convert values to Pdf in my Android
  app And Persian words disappear in pdf.
- I searched many sites and found similar answers, all of which stated
  that I should use xb fonts.
- I downloaded 21 xb fonts and put them in the assets folder and set
  them on my text with setTypeFace, although the fonts are set on the
  text, but the Persian letters are still not visible.
- I put the project images below this text.

[image]
***this is result:***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using unicode instead of persian letters

```
public static final String DEST = "results/fonts/arabic_rtl.pdf";
public static final String FONT = "resources/fonts/NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf";
public static final String ARABIC = "\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0639\u0631 
\u0627\u0644\u0627\u062c\u0645\u0627\u0644\u064a";

public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new 
    FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    Font f = FontFactory.getFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    Phrase p = new Phrase("This is incorrect: ");
    p.add(new Chunk(ARABIC, f));
    p.add(new Chunk(": 50.00 USD"));
    document.add(p);

    p = new Phrase("This is correct: ");
    p.add(new Chunk(ARABIC, f));
    p.add(new Phrase(": 50.00"));
    
    ColumnText canvas = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
    canvas.setSimpleColumn(36, 750, 559, 780);
    canvas.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR);
    canvas.addElement(p);
    canvas.go();

    document.close();
   }
```

Comment: I wrote your code with 'NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf' font and Arabic characters, but the Arabic characters disappeared again.